# cannot display php code in local host

Tags: php

I have been googling answers for hours and cannot find a solution as to, how can I preview my PHP code through my local host using XAMPP?

I have tried changing the ports and I have tried typing in different syntax but nothing seems to work.

I have a file called "test.php" and I just want to see it run on the browser but it doesn't.

All it either does is take me to the XAMPP dashboard or it says "page not found".

If I type my C://"myfilename" into the browser it just brings up the source code.

Please help!

Comment: Doing that will not go via the web server and therefore there will be no PHP compiler in the loop, as its called by Apache.

Comment: Lookup how to us localhost properly

Comment: Put your script into the `xampp\htdocs` folder and launch it by putting `localhost/myfilename.php` in the BROWSERS address bar. Make sure the filename has the `.php` extension

Comment: I have put localhost\test.php in the address bar which it is saved in the htdocs folder. I just don’t understand why it doesn’t work? I have watched and read multiple tutorials. The only thing I haven’t done was uninstall it and reinstall it and try it again.

Comment: Also @RiggsFolly how do I call php then? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is your XAMPP stack online?

Comment: I believe so! How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

In the file explorer, where you have the file,click on view >show>file name extensions to make sure the file extension is in php format

Comment: this could have been the comment, if you dont have enough reps for comment, hold on. Thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33119908)